# pandas - intersect dataframes by index.name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes that share (some) ids (specified in index.name) and I want to intersect them.

So given:

```
dfA.index.name = 'id'
dfB.index.name = 'id'
```

and `dfA` being like:

```
        count
id       
1         15
3         16
8          1
```

and `dfB` being like:

```
        owns
id 
1       True
3       False
12      False
```

I want to obtain dfC being like:

```
        count    owns
id 
1         15      True
3         16      False
```

I tried

```
s1 = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, how='inner', on=['id'])
```

without success

Answer (score 7):

I'd use [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) in this case:

```
dfC = dfA.join(dfB, how='inner')
```

Comment: `join` performs a left join. The OP wants an inner join. But you can pass `how="inner"`.

Comment: adding a new way :-)

Answer (score 4):

You should merge on indexes, not on columns:

```
s1 = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Assigning a name to an index does not make it a column.

Answer (score 2):

I will using `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],join ='inner',axis=1)
Out[475]: 
    count   owns
id              
1      15   True
3      16  False
```